# Is it possible to launch SMS with Oracle APEX Automation?

Tags: oracle, automation, sms, apex

I was hoping to find a solution with scheduled once a month SMS delivery to atleast 40 mobile numbers through Oracle APEX automation if it is possible.

Comment: you would need an external API to communicate with a service that can provide SMS or text to audio messages. One option is to use ClickSend https://www.clicksend.com. You have also an API built by Jeff Kemp on GitHub https://github.com/jeffreykemp/clicksend-plsql-api . Once you have this, you can create an automation for this. Read about ClickSend , it is not free.

Comment: i understand the api requirement, i just need a more simpler approach on how to integrate certain code/s on automation,,i already checked mr kemps github,, im quiet confused where to start.